# Accessing files in directory outside of Anaconda

Tags: python-3.x, anaconda

Newb here to python/anaconda.

I'm trying to run a python script (and it reads other files local to its directory) which doesn't belong to the same directory as the Anaconda directory where I'm executing the python command there.

So I am trying to run a python script (lets say it resides in path B directory) from the Anaconda python (say path A directory).  Within this script, there is a call to reading a local file so we have only the fileName.py and then the command prompt spits out this error:

```
C:\Users\usernameABC\Anaconda3>python C:\Users\usernameABC\Documents\GitHub\python\ThinkStats2\code\nsfg.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\usernameABC\Documents\GitHub\python\ThinkStats2\code\nsfg.py", line 165, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\usernameABC\Documents\GitHub\python\ThinkStats2\code\nsfg.py", line 130, in main
    resp = ReadFemResp()
  File "C:\Users\usernameABC\Documents\GitHub\python\ThinkStats2\code\nsfg.py", line 27, in ReadFemResp
    dct = thinkstats2.ReadStataDct(dct_file)
  File "C:\Users\usernameABC\Documents\GitHub\python\ThinkStats2\code\thinkstats2.py", line 2646, in ReadStataDct
    for line in open(dct_file, **options):
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '2002FemResp.dct'
```

I basically just want to run the script, whether its in Anaconda or wherever is the easiest or most natural that most experienced coders would.  Please help!  Thanks in advance for feedback!

Answer (score 0):

You can change your current working directory using the

`cd` (change directory) command

You can also modify the script so that you can specify where the files are that you want to access. If you show us the script that you are running we may be able to help more.